# Select in WHERE contains all condition SQL

Tags: mysql

I have multiple dropdown menu with list of options

```
    <select id="options">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="1">Good</option>
    <option value="2">Bad</option>
    <option value="3">Okay</option>
    </select>
<select id="options1">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="1">Good</option>
    <option value="2">Bad</option>
    <option value="3">Okay</option>
    </select>
<select id="options2">
    <option value="all" selected>All</option>
    <option value="1">Good</option>
    <option value="2">Bad</option>
    <option value="3">Okay</option>
    </select>
```

I use this query

```
        $result = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['options']);
        $result1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['options1']);
        $result2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['options2']);

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `option` = '$result' AND `option1` = '$result1' AND `option2` = '$result2'");
```

If option "all" selected, the SQL returns nothing since no record as "all" in the table. How can I make it return all options if "all" selected ? Considering different dropdown IDs

Comment: Avoid the Where condition in SQL statement, if `$result` having value "all"

Answer (score 0):

Like.

```
$result = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['options']);

if($result  == "all"){
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
}else{
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `option` = '$result'");
}
```

This will help you

Comment: What if I have multiple select IDs ?
users can select any combinations of IDs.
Can there be one common SQL for them ?

Comment: Use SQL in operator @Rubiks like:  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, " SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `option` IN= ('$result') ");
$result must have comma separated values.

Comment: This will not help if $result is assigned to different options ID column
e.g. $result = all from id options
$result = all from id options1

Comment: nicce `sql` injection ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Where is it ? Please check gain "mysqli_real_escape_string"